# Reverse Cocoa bindings and identify the bindings target view?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a custom class that exposes an `NSString` property. In Interface Builder I've bound the `title` of an `NSButton` to the property of my custom class.

Is it possible to get a reference to the `NSButton` instance from within my custom class?

Essentially I'm trying to locate all the user interface elements that are bound to the property in my custom class.

Comment: I don't have a complete solution to offer, but I'd suggest overriding `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`. I think you need to do that on the bound controller.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to do it leveraging a different binding, view subclasses, or KVO.

Comment: `- (void *)observationInfo` might yield useful info too, I'm not sure.

Comment: There can't be a unique answer because multiple views (or other objects) might be bound to the same object and property. As for noa's suggestion, the observer *may* be the view that is bound to your object, or it may be some helper object that will be opaque to you.

Comment: Lots of good suggestions above. Ken is right, all methods yield some internal helper/wrapper classes that are not publicly exposed. For example `NSKeyValueObservationInfo`, `NSObjectParameterBinder`, and `NSKeyValueObservance`. I guess I could create headers for those, but the risk is that the interface changes in the future...

Comment: Still – what is it you're actually wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @noa I have a class that exposes arbitrary properties via `valueForUndefinedKey:`. I'd like to know which properties are bound and what other objects reference those properties.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but still not what you want to accomplish by that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this sounds like an anti-pattern and/or a bad idea. That said, there are a couple of things to bear in mind. Multiple observers could be bound to your property. You can override `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` and `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` (and `removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:`) and then maintain your own array of observers. With that approach I would caution you that you may need to go to extra effort for the array to not retain observers, as traditionally KV observations don't retain the observing object, and you will likely run into leaks/heap growth if you start retaining them by putting them in an `NSArray`.

The other gotcha with overriding `addObserver:...` and `removeObserver:...` is that, without considerable extra work, you wont know if the observation is for a binding or for something else (like, say, a dependent keyPath notification). One possible workaround for that would be to interrogate the observer via `infoForBinding:` on all `exposedBindings` on a later runloop pass using `performSelector:afterDelay:`. (I think I just threw up in my mouth a little bit for suggesting this.)

Relying on private implementation details of the KVO system is not likely to be a good approach, unless your goal is simply to better understand how KVO works, but it sounds like you're actually trying to accomplish something.

Really, this whole approach just feels like a recipe for disaster. It sounds like an MVC violation from the get-go.  Why would the model object need to know about the view objects? Whatever you're trying to accomplish here would almost certainly be better accomplished by having the nib be owned by an NSViewController subclass which has IBOutlets for all the UI elements, and properties for the model. That object would then be in a position to more cleanly manage the apparently complex relationship between your view and model objects without runtime trickery. Since you've not elaborated on the ultimate goal of this trickery, it's hard to say what the best approach would be.